# PHP MYSQL QUERY ORDER BY desc problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have two field name `$date` and `$time`.

```
     date  |  time
2011/01/09 | 08:22:25
2011/01/09 | 13:00:55
2011/01/09 | 17:45:18
2011/01/09 | 17:30:26
2011/01/08 | 18:22:00
2011/01/08 | 12:06:39
```

How to let the newest before the oldest. I want them to be:

```
     date  |  time
2011/01/09 | 17:45:18
2011/01/09 | 17:30:26
2011/01/09 | 13:00:55
2011/01/09 | 08:22:25
2011/01/08 | 18:22:00
2011/01/08 | 12:06:39
```

How to write a `select * from article order by...desc...`? Thanks.

Comment: Is the date in the format YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY/DD/MM?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY date desc, time desc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from article order by date desc, time desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time` DESC;
```

should do just fine.

Comment: The `WHERE 1` is unnecessary.

Comment: It is, but I like to have it anyway, so when I read my code I don't think "Woah, did I forget something"? It's like an explicit "really, really, get ALL data".

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM CAFTERIA ORDER BY sl_no DESC;"
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answer to this question and a bit of pain I discovered the following worked for me. This answer includes a PHP example for `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. They need to be in that `ORDER` with `LIMIT` last of it doesn't work.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Page_Relations WHERE Child=$article_id ORDER BY Page_ID ASC LIMIT 0 , 30 ";
```

I wanted to create a context sensitive menu list where the pages in the index are ordered by a `Page_ID` number.